# Why does this table mess up the rest of the document?

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I have a simple markdown text i'm writing, and i may be messing it up with indentations and whatnot, but this Raw text :
[image: Raw Text]

Renders like this :

[image]

And i don't know what's wrong with it because, in the raw part, it stopped recognizing the indentations (notice that there are no colors after the table) and its rendering the second part as raw text again, even giving it an horizontal scroll bar at the bottom

I'm assuming it is the table messing the rest of the document?

Comment: Can you add raw code to play with it?

Comment: rendering correctly for me in both vscode and github editors.

Comment: @HarshGundecha Yes, i left some in here : https://pastebin.com/iM770XQs

Answer (score 0):

1. The reason why it is behaving like that is after a limit the whitespaces causes the line to be interpreted as blockquote.
2. The number of indentation in point 1 and 2 seems to be different in your screenshot causing different rendering.
3. Below are 2 example or unexpected and expected snipped respectively.

---

#### Snippet with unexpected behavior

1. Sample text

| First Header | Second Header |
| --- | --- |
| Content from cell 1 | Content from cell 2 |
| Content in the first column | Content in the second column |

```
2. This seems to be incorrectly rendered ️  
  1. sub point 1  
  2. sub point 2
```

---

#### Snippet with expected behavior

1. Sample text

| First Header | Second Header |
| --- | --- |
| Content from cell 1 | Content from cell 2 |
| Content in the first column | Content in the second column |

2. This seems to be correctly rendered ️

   1. sub point 1
   2. sub point 2

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table is supposed to be part of "1.", indent it four spaces further than the list item to treat it as a continuation of that list item:

```
1. Top-level list (not shown in your screenshot but I'm assuming it's there because of the indentation)

    1. Second-level list

        | Table header |
        |-
        | Table cell |

    1. Second-level list
```

This should render like so:

1. Top-level list (not shown in your screenshot but I'm assuming it's there because of the indentation)

   1. Second-level list

      | Table header |
      | --- |
      | Table cell |
   2. Second-level list

Quoting [the documentation](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#list):

> List items may consist of multiple paragraphs. Each subsequent paragraph in a list item must be indented by either 4 spaces or one tab

The original Markdown didn't support tables at all, but the logic here is similar to how it handles blockquotes:

> To put a blockquote within a list item, the blockquote's `>` delimiters need to be indented:
>
> ```
> *   A list item with a blockquote:
>
>     > This is a blockquote
>     > inside a list item.
> ```

Currently, your table is ending the lists entirely. This makes your "2." item into as a code block since it is indented by four spaces.

There are [further examples](https://github.github.com/gfm/#list-items) in the Github-Flavored Markdown documentation.